# check any object's property is set to true

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am just trying to see, how to know that any property in `globalSettings` is set to true:

```
<div :class="checkIfAnyGsIsOverridden(globalSettings) ? 'text-success' : 'text-muted")>Lorem Ipsum</div>


globalSettings: {
  setting1: true,
  setting2: false,
  setting3: false
}

checkIfAnyGsIsOverridden (obj) {
  return obj.filter(item => {
    // not sure what code should go here it check true or false 
    // that returns the length
  }).length;
}
```

Got this error `TypeError: obj.filter is not a function` and later I got to understand that `.filter` works with `array`.

Also tried this but no luck because it always return false:

```
checkIfAnyGsIsOverridden (obj) {
  console.log(Object.keys(obj).every(k => {
    return obj[k] === true
  }))
}
```

I know there is alway hard way but I like to do something simple and dynamic like above:

```
if globalSetting.setting1 === true { 
  // do something 
}
```

Comment: Just use `some` instead of `every` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also tried this but no luck because it always return false:

Since you are checking the opposite - if `every` property is set to `true`

Use `some` instead

```
checkIfAnyGsIsOverridden (obj) {
  console.log(Object.keys(obj).some(k => {
    return obj[k] === true
  }))
}
```

Above code will return `true`, if any one property is set to `true`.